# How to automatically generate the modulefile for Intel compilers

Tags: tcl, icc, environment-modules, modulefile

Do you know a way to automatically generate the modulefile for Intel compilers without using the env2 script?

Answer (score 1):

Using latest version of Modules (v4.6+), the `module` command gets a new sub-command called [sh-to-mod](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MIGRATING.html#sh-to-mod-sub-command) that translates the environment changes performed by a given script into modulefile commands.

```
$ module sh-to-mod sh /path/to/foo-1.2/foo-setup.sh arg1
#%Module
prepend-path    PATH /path/to/foo-1.2/bin
set-alias       foo {foobin -q -l}
setenv          FOOENV arg1
```

The [source-sh](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MIGRATING.html#source-sh-modulefile-command) modulefile Tcl command is also introduced in version 4.6 of Modules to directly translate the environment changes performed by a given script as if it was the content of the modulefile currently being evaluated.

On older version of Modules, a standalone script named `createmodule.py` is provided to achieve such script to modulefile translation.